# Apache + mod_lisp + clisp

Tags: apache, lisp, clisp

How to to configure apache + mod_lisp + clisp and set up a "Hello World!"? I couldn't find any complete howto on the subject. Thanks.

Edit: Vebjorn's solution works, but then I don't how to code the "hello world!". Can anyone tell me how to proceed? There's something like SWANKing the clisp, then connect to it with SLIME, but then when I launch mod_lisp's demo, the test page is not served and my slime doesn't return?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

1. Download http://www.fractalconcept.com:8000/public/open-source/mod_lisp/mod_lisp.c

   - Compile and install Apache module with `sudo apxs -i -c mod_lisp.c`
   - Add the following to your `httpd.conf`:

     ```
     LoadModule lisp_module libexec/httpd/mod_lisp.so
     AddModule mod_lisp.c
     LispServer 127.0.0.1 3000 "foo"
     <Location /foo>
     SetHandler lisp-handler
     </Location>
     ```
2. Restart apache with `sudo apachectl restart`

   - Download example of Lisp-side handling in CLISP: http://www.fractalconcept.com/fcweb/download/modlisp-clisp.lisp
3. Start CLISP and evaluate:

   ```
   (load "modlisp-clisp")
   (modlisp:modlisp-server)
   ```
4. Point your browser to http://localhost/foo.  You should see:

> mod_lisp 2.0
>
> This is a constant html string sent by
>   mod_lisp 2.0 + CLISP + apache + Linux

Comment: This is **great**! With your guide, I successfully get it run on my server. Apache v2.2.14, clisp. Because I'm using Apache2, so AddModule is out of date, remove it. I add "LoadModule", "LispServer" into mod-available direcotry, created lisp.conf, lisp.load file. I add "Location" into my site config file under site-available directory.

Answer (score 1):

What backend are you using? If none, I would suggest trying [Hunchentoot](http://www.weitz.de/hunchentoot/#mod_lisp) or, even better, [UCW](http://trac.common-lisp.net/ucw/wiki/IntroInstallation).

Both of those links will take you to the installation instructions, ending with a Hello World kind of page.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.newartisans.com/blog_files/common.lisp.with.apache.php) seems to be a fairly thorough "how-to" guide to set up Common Lisp on Apache using mod_lisp2.

> If all has gone as planned, you should now have a Common Lisp app server running behind Apache

Comment: Thanks but I want to use clisp and your solution uses sbcl. There should be not much differences though.